# Why does Forge not find my texture for my custom background?

Tags: gui, minecraft-modding

I am creating a minecraft mod that improves the main menu for my minecraft server. At first I wanted to create the background, but somehow when I try to start minecraft it closes and I get a nullpointerexception because minecraft didn't find my background.

```
public class ThundrialMenu extends GuiScreen {

    @Override
    public void initGui() {

    }

    @Override
    public void drawScreen(int mouseX, int mouseY, float partialTicks) {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int background = rnd.nextInt(3)+1;
        String backgroundLocation = "/assets/thundrial/gui/Background"+background+".png";
        this.drawBackground(mc.renderEngine.getTexture(new ResourceLocation(backgroundLocation)).getGlTextureId());
        super.drawScreen(mouseX, mouseY, partialTicks);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateScreen() {
        super.updateScreen();
    }
}
```

This is the folder where the pictures are located:

[image: The folder where my pictures are located]

Why does Minecraft not find those pictures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the correct way to create a resource location is as so:

```
new ResourceLocation("thundrial", "gui/Background" + background + ".png");
```

The first parameter of ResourceLocation is your Mod-ID/assets directory. From your image I can see this is "thundrial". This should find your assets correctly. The second parameter is the path from `"assets/thundrial/"` to your image.

My second point is, what you're doing wont render your background image. The method `drawBackground(i)` is used by MC to draw the default options menu and not your own custom background. The `i` parameter is a UV value, not an image id.

For as far as I know the easiest and most simplistic way to do what you're doing is to render over the background by using the bind method: `mc.renderEngine.bindTexture(location)` and then using the gui's `drawTexturedModalRect(x, y, u, v, w, h)` to draw the image over the top.

Comment: The second parameter should be `"gui/"+background+".png"` in this case.

Comment: I've updated the post with that in, thanks @immibis.